# Why the bind click event do not response?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue app like bellow:

`index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vuejs-test01</title>

    <link href="./src/assets/styles/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  >
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div id="bag"></div>

      <div id="bag-helth">
        <div :style="{ width:helth + '%' }"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="control">
        <button @click="punch" v-show="!ended">click</button>
        <button @click="restart">restart</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

`main.js` code, in the render function it renders the App.vue:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import './assets/styles/global.styl'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),   
})
```

My `style.css` code, the css file bellow are showing the styles:

```
#bag {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../imgs/02.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
}

#bag-helth {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px #000 solid;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

#bag-helth div {
  height: 20px;
  background: crimson;
}

#control {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

My `Vue.app` code, you see the `export default` :

```
<template>

</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data: {
      helth: 100,
      ended: false,
    },
    methods: {
      punch: function () {
        this.helth -= 10

        if (this.helth <= 0) {
          this.ended = true
        }
      },
      restart: function () {
        this.helth = 100
        this.ended = false
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

In the browser result:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

When I click the buttons, there is no response.

---

**EDIT-1**

I found if in the `index.html`, I add the value `{{ helth }}` in the `#bag` div:

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="bag">{{ helth }}</div>
...
```

the template do not analysis the data:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Put your html codes in `App.vue` file between `template` tags, not in `index.html`. so your `index.html` will be like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>vuejs-test01</title>

 <link href="./src/assets/styles/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  >
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app"></div>
 <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and your `App.vue` be like

```
<template>
 <div id="app">
    <div id="bag">{{helth}}</div>

  <div id="bag-helth">
    <div :style="{ width:helth + '%' }"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="control">
    <button @click="punch" v-show="!ended">click</button>
    <button @click="restart">restart</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data: {
      helth: 100,
      ended: false,
    },
    methods: {
      punch: function () {
        this.helth -= 10

        if (this.helth <= 0) {
          this.ended = true
        }
      },
      restart: function () {
        this.helth = 100
        this.ended = false
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: I follow you, but there shows nothing in the browser now.

Comment: Oh sorry, updated `index.html` code to include the build file :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some places wrong in your project:

1. You should put the template code in your `App.vue`:

   ```
     <div id="bag-helth">
       <div :style="{ width:helth + '%' }"></div>
     </div>

     <div id="control">
       <button @click="punch" v-show="!ended">click</button>
       <button @click="restart">restart</button>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

In your `index.html`, you should keep a empty div `<div id="app"></div>` and `build.js` like bellow:

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
</body>
```

So, in the `main.js` then can render the App.vue to the index.html `<div id="app"></app>`:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)  // there render the App.vue to the el node.
})
```

2. The `App.vue` is a component, not a Vue instance, the data should be a function:

   ```
   export default {
     data: function() {
       return {
         helth: 100,
         ended: false
       }
     },
   ...
   ```